# Render on canvas

Tags: openlayers

I have been looking to create a legend info control on the map that is also visible on a map when taking a screen shot. I like to know how to paint on top of a layer or on top of the mapframe. 
If I create an osm layer and uses code below it works but ...

```
this.osmLayer.on('postrender', function (event) {
     me.updateBackground(event.context);
 });
```

if the layer is an vectorlayer and there are no features active there is no postrender event ... and if there are active features on the layer but they are out off current extent there is no postrender event to act on ...
Any nice ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a dummy vector layer with an invisible global feature https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-image-20f7f and render the image on that

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [CanvasBase control](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/blob/master/src/control/CanvasBase.js) in ol-ext to display controls on the canvas.
It can be used for creating subclasses.
See [examples online](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/canvas/map.canvas.control.html).

Comment: I've looked at ol-ext and the code is very nice.I just wanted to learn how to make my own controls.